# What is the best way to place text over an Rive animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, text, rive

I am new to Flutter. I want to place some text that will have values changing over a Rive animation. What is the best way to make sure that the text stays in the same place over the animation no matter the screen size?

Lets say these 3 red boxes have some telemetry data as an example.

[image]

Will the Stack widget with position work? Before I go down this rabbit hole I think I need some advice on how to show data in or over a Rive animation.

Comment: Were you able to make the widgets inside the stack responsive ? My text widget does not always align the way I want it. Did you find any solution for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Stack` is always the answer :) Wrap the `Rive` animation with it, and use a `text` widget wherever you want.

Comment: Well if I try that and I run the same app on a tablet that shows the text at the correct place on the phone then the text is not at the same spot.

Comment: Can I fix the Rive Animation to be a certain size so the text wont move?

Comment: Responsiveness can be achieved through various ways. There isn't a silver bullet afaik. You can try wrapping the `Stack` to `SizedBox` with your custom dimensions, then wrap `Rive` animation with `Positioned.fill` widget so it takes up the whole `Stack` and last, wrap the `Text` widget with `Positioned` to determine its position in the `Stack`.

Comment: So I first placed a container and gave it a size. This seems to work more or less. as it gives the Rive animation the same size on all the different devices. I will design the Animation in such a way so there is a bit of play. But at least I have an idea what to do. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Jaco Fourie, Even after wrapping widget with SizedBox and gave stack the Positioned.fill , still its not responsive. Can you educate us about how to make it responsive ?